# How to print context content in the template?

Tags: python, django

How can I print or iterate over all the variables available in the context from the template code?

I know about `{% debug %}` but it contains too much information. I'd just like to print variable names available in the current context.

Is there a way to do this without writing custom tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) - gives you this on the Templates tab, along a whole range of other useful debugging information.

Comment: Any way of doing this _without_ modifying application-wide configuration?

Answer (score 7):

If you use class-based views you can just give the current context like a variable to context:

```
class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['ctx'] = ctx
        return ctx
```

Than you can access the context with `{{ctx}}`