# retrieving all Django HTML variables

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm looking to extract all variables in a html template in django such as `{{variable1}}` and place them into a list. This list will be used to query a database for the corresponding values. so `variable1` could correspond to `Home Page` etc. and I would pass back `{'variable1' : 'Home Page'}`

Is there something built in or a third party application to do this? The closest thing I found was [this in Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext).

using Django 1.11, python 3.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999811/how-to-print-context-content-in-the-template